# Why JS loop returns not all results by preudo code?

Tags: javascript

I have tried to realize pseudo code in JS:

```
function merge(sea, fresh)
 result ← List.new
 while not (sea.empty and fresh.empty)
 if sea.top_item > fresh.top_item
 fish ← sea.remove_top_item
 else
 fish ← fresh.remove_top_item
 result.append(fish)
return result
```

JS function should merge two arrays:

```
let list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let list2 = [10, 11, 15];

function merge(list1: any, list2: any[]) { 
    let result = [];

    while (list1.length && list2.length) {
        let fish; // temp variable
        if (list1[0] > list2[0]) { 
            fish = list1.shift(); // get always greatest element
        } else { 
         fish = list2.shift();
        }

        result.push(fish);
    }    

    return result; // Return result
}
```

Call:

```
console.log(merge(list1, list2));
```

Obviously I get result: `[10, 11, 15]` instead

```
 [1,2,3,4, 10, 11, 15]
```

Where is my mistake?

[image: merge two lists]

Comment: Your `list1` values in your example will never be able to pass `if (list1[0] > list2[0])` condition, because every one of them is smaller that the values in `list2`

Comment: Yes, I know, but I have found this example in Computer Science book and tried to reproduce in JS

Comment: Well, you say in your question that this function should merge array, which it doesn't - it returns new array with biggest elements(kinda). So you want to merge two arrays or you want to get biggest elements? What does the book say? If you want to merge them, just use [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Comment: I expect as said in books, merge two lists in alphabet order, using iterative way

Comment: Look at iillustration from books

Comment: I believe there are multiple mistakes in your code (as @JayNyxed hinted at). For starters, look at the condition in your while-loop and think about why you might be breaking out of the loop early (hint: there's a discrepancy between your code and the pseudocode you provided).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that kind of merge it is necessary to look at `length` of both arrays. In your example: when one of the arrays ends you stop merging.

```js
var list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var list2 = [10, 11, 15];
var ers = merge(list1, list2)
console.log(ers);

function merge(sea, fresh) { 
    let result = [];

    while (sea.length > 0 || fresh.length > 0) { //OR is very important here, so if one array ends, we keep looking in the second one
        let fish; // temp variable
        let i1;
        let i2;
        if(sea.length > 0){
         i1 = sea[0];
        }
        if(fresh.length > 0){
          i2 = fresh[0];
        }
        if ((i1 != undefined && i1 < i2) || i2 == undefined) { 
            fish = sea.shift(); // get always greatest element
        } else { 
          fish = fresh.shift();
        }

        result.push(fish);
    }    

    return result; // Return result
}
```

Comment: So it was typo in the book in AND instead ||, thank you, it works only when all list are sorted

Comment: Also I did not get, when i1 is undefined why because see is empty, then always works undefined < i2, and it means `fish = fresh.shift();` never works, is not?

Comment: Why `(undefined < 3)` is false for example? It is used in your exmaple

Comment: It is not really possible to compare `undefined` to int, so as soon as first array ends `i1 < i2` is going to be `false`. 
I also can tell that testing if there is a value is a great practice, so I'm gonna edit the code to apply it =)

Comment: Actually I just found an error. Let me fix this real quick

Comment: As you can see
in line `((i1 != undefined && i1 < i2) || i2 == undefined)` checking for undefined is great practice. If I dont check for `i2 == undefined` then with arrays like `var list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6];
var list2 = [1, 3, 5];`
previous version will fall into error